# How do I stop Jackson JSON mapper from implicitly casting to a String?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON array that I want to make sure only contains strings.  Jackson implicitly casts integers and dates to strings.  I want to make sure that every element in the JSON array is in fact a string.

```
    Object[] badModuleArray = new Object[]{"case", 1, 2, "employee", new Date()};

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonModules = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(badModuleArray);

    try
    {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
        mapper.readValue(modules, typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        logger.error("something other than strings in JSON object");

    }
```

In the above example, I want the ObjectMapper to not cast integer, dates, etc to Strings.  I want an exception thrown if each element in the JSON array is not a string.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson is casting each object to a string because you've told it that you want a `List<String>`.

Instead, ask Jackson for a `List<Object>` and examine the contents of the List yourself to throw an error if any of them are not a String:

```
List list = objectMapper.readValue(jsonModules, typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, Object.class));
for (Object item : list) {
    System.out.println(item + " is a: " + item.getClass());
    if (!(item instanceof String)) {
        System.out.println("Not a string!");
    }
}
```

For JSON of `["case",1,2,"employee",1358444552861]` I get:

> case is a: class java.lang.String
>   1 is a: class java.lang.Integer
>   Not a string!
>   2 is a: class java.lang.Integer
>   Not a string!
>   employee is a: class java.lang.String
>   1358444552861 is a: class java.lang.Long
>   Not a string!

Comment: This is correct. Another possibility is to add custom content deserializer using `@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=MyValueDeserializer.class)`, to do checking.